# How to get current matplolib plot title?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I programmatically get the current title of the figure?

For some functions of the `matplotlib` api (e.g. `xticks`, `xlim`), the getter as is the same as the setter, but calling the function with no arguments (`plt.xticks()`).

But `plt.title()` raises an error (as the argument is mandatory).

Any other way of getting the current plot title?

Comment: [get_title()](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_title.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the object orientated API, there is a [`set_title()`](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title) and a [`get_title()`](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_title.html) function:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([1,2,3])
ax.set_title("Testing the title")

print (ax.get_title())
# Testing the title

plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you can still use `get_title()` using `plt.gca()`

```
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.title("Testing the title")

print (plt.gca().get_title())
# Testing the title
```

Comment: right. But do you know a way to catch it without using the object oriented API?

Comment: @maxou I've updated the answer, see if that is better?